# Search XML file for a word and update

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

How would you search a xml file using c# code and replace a certain value

In this case 
I want to cahnge

```
version="5.25"
```

to

```
version="6.25"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using linq to xml:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(yourXMLGoesHere);
var elementsWithVersionAttribute) = doc.Descendants()
                 .Where(e => e.Attribute("version")!=null)
                 .Where(e => e.Attribute("version").Value == "5.25");

foreach(var element in elementsWithVersionAttribute)
{
  element.SetAttributeValue("version", "6.25");
}
```

You could probably make the above code a bit shorter - but hopefully it is easier to follow with the query separate from the loop.